# Show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3} \rightrightarrows$ on $[0,A],A > 0$ and $\lim_{x\to 1}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}=\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification, continuity, uniform-convergence

> Show $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$ is
>   uniformly convergent on $[0,A]$ for any $A \gt 0$.
>
> Then prove
>
> $$ \lim_{x \to 1} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{n^3+1}.$$

My attempt:

Let $A \gt 0$ be given. Let $\displaystyle M_n := \frac{A^2}{n^2}$.

Then $\displaystyle \left| \frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3} \right| \lt \left| \frac{nx^2}{n^3} \right|=\frac{x^2}{n^2} \leq M_n, \forall x \in [0,A]$. Also $\sum_{n=1}^\infty M_n < \infty$, so by Weierstrass M test, the series converges uniformly on $[0,A]$.

Now for the second part, to simplify things, I wrote it down like this:

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{nx^2}{n^3+x^3}$. Prove $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = f(1)$.

Now isn't this equivalent of asking if $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$?

We know $f(x)$ is uniformly convergent on $[0,A]$ so it is continuous on $[0,A]$. Pick $A=2$, then $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=1$, and hence the limit converges to $f(1)$.

Is there anything wrong with my second proof/argument?

Comment: Your proof is fine if the series started with $n=0$. But there is  a term corresponding to $n=-1$ which is $-\frac {x^{2}} {x^{3}-1}$. This is not defined at $x=1$. So your proof breaks down!

Comment: Oh. That's a typo. It should start from $n=1$.

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: Whatever you have done is correct.